# Returning list of items in SQL table through controller

Tags: php, laravel

> I'm Looking for help on returning specific data from SQL. Below is a function in the controller. However this returns data from the same column

```
public function view_Questionnaire(Questionnaire $Questionnaire) {

$cats = question::lists('Answer1', 'id');

$Questionnaire->option_name = unserialize($Questionnaire-option_name);

return view('questionnaire.view', compact('Questionnaire', 'cats'));
```

}

> My SQL table has the titles of the following 'id','questionnaire_id','user_id','title', 'Answer1', 'Answer2', 'Answer3', 'Answer4', 'Answer5', 'Created at', 'Updated at'.
>
> I need my data to return the 'Answer 1' - 'Answer 5' fields for each separate question

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to create a accessor field (function on model)
for this put in you model the function

```
public function getAnswersOneFiveAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->answer1}-{$this->answer5}";
}
```

if you are using lists

```
$cats = question::lists('answers_one_five', 'id');
```

if you are using pluck

```
$cats = question::get()->pluck('answers_one_five', 'id');
```

Comment: I’ve tried this, however it doesn’t seem to work. Thank-you for your response